# Shortest distance as measured in norm $||\cdot ||$ from point to a sphere in norm $||*||$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

I recently found this theorem, which is used in some clustering algorithms:

Let $x,v \in \mathbb{R}^p$, $r>0$, $||\cdot ||_{\ast}$ be a given norm on $\mathbb{R}^p$ and $\partial B_{||\cdot||_{\ast}}(v,r) = \{ y\in\mathbb{R}^p: ||y-v||_{\ast}=r \}$ be the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at $v$. Then the shortest distance, as measured by $||\cdot ||_{\dagger}$, from any point in $\partial B_{||\cdot||_{\ast}}(v,r)$ to $x$ is $\left|\ ||x-v||_{\ast}-r \right|.$

I know that this holds for $||\cdot ||_2,$ but how would one prove that this holds for any two pairs of norms $||\cdot ||_{\ast}$ and $||\cdot ||_{\dagger}$?

I've tried tracking down the original article, because all the articles I've seen that have cited it do exactly that, just cite it, without giving the proof.

This isn't homework or anything like that, I'm just curious as to what approach one could use when trying to prove this?

EDIT: Source of this claim: [Page 65](https://books.google.hr/books?id=3-ubOzjjneUC&pg=PR5&lpg=PR5&dq=norm+induced+shell+prototype+clustering&source=bl&ots=MAIbO6jQn5&sig=L_JfU1Wm42aQbBnxlSWil4nWzxQ&hl=hr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihpcGUmYLNAhVB2xoKHRHECosQ6AEIOzAF#v=onepage&q=norm%20induced%20shell%20prototype%20clustering&f=false).

Now that there is a counterexample in one of the answers, I suppose that there is actually only one norm here. I apologize for the confusion, but as you will see from the source, the two norms are marked differently, which led me to the conclusion that they are not the same.

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you'd put subscripts to distinguish different norms.

Comment: I didn't use subscripts because I thought they might make it seem like a certain norm the $p$-norm is, or something similar. If you have suggestions for subscripts, please let me know. Also, the norm which is used in $||y-v||$ and $||x-v||$ is the $||*||$, the norm $||\cdot ||$ is the one in which the distance between the point and the sphere is measured. @SeverinSchraven

Comment: You can use norm subscripts like $\ast$ or $\dagger$

Comment: As how I interpret this, is that $\| \cdot \|_{\dagger}$ is just notation for $\| y \|_{\dagger} := \inf_{y \in \delta B_{\| \cdot \|_{*}}(v,r)} \{ \| x-y \|_{*}\}$. So you do not have two pairs of norms, but rather one norm and a function of that norm and some parameters $v$ and $r$, denote by $\| \cdot \|_{\dagger}$.

Comment: @Hetebrij No, there are two different norms here. However, now that you posted this, it made me think differently about the norms. Could it be that only the sphere is given in one norm and the other norm is the one which we are trying to minimize?

Comment: Is it possible that you changed during your last edit $\vert \ \Vert x - v \Vert_{\dagger} - r\vert$ to $\vert \ \Vert x - v \Vert_{\ast} - r\vert$?

Comment: Thanks for the new notations. Do you have a source for the claim?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven As you will see from the source of the claim which I just added, you can't really tell which norm is which, so my edit was made in the way I thought it should be.

Comment: @LaurentDuval Source added.

Comment: @T_M OK. I have added another source that suggests there was only one norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the same norms a demonstration uses the following. Using [norm subadditivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition), for any $b$ on the sphere:

$$\|b\| \le \|b-x\|+  \|x\|$$
and 
$$\|x\| \le \|x-b\|+  \|b\|$$
so all in all:
$$\|x-b\| \ge \max(\|b\|-\|x\|,\|x\|-\|b\|) = |\|x\|-r|\,.$$

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work for different norms in general. Take $ p=2$, a $l_q$ and a $l_r$ two norms, $q,r \ge 1$. Take $v$ at the origin (because it plays little role here), $r=1$, $x=(1,1)$ on the diagonal. Then the minimum $l_r$ norm to the $l_q$ ball is $m=2^{1/r}(1-1/2^{1/q})$. And your formula gives $n=2^{1/q}-1$.

The two quantities are equal if and only if $ q =r$. Note that the above generalizes with higher dimension $p\ge 2$.

[EDIT] I have just found a paper by Bezdek in 1995: [Shell-prototype clustering models](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICNN.1995.488860). The theorem given (cropped for the record) is:

[image: NIPS theorem]

Apparently there is only one "given" norm. I guess that the $\|*\|$ stands for a wildcard-type notations meaning "any argument", while $\|\cdot\|$ is the functional notation.

Comment: I think this works only if the two norms coincide.

Comment: I might have  fooled myself with the norm notation. Counter example with $l_2$ and Chebychev norm in mind.

Comment: I edited the norm notation. We have the space $(\mathbb{R}^p,||\cdot ||_{\ast})$, but the problem of finding the distance between the point and sphere is to be measured in $\\\cdot ||_{\dagger}.$

Comment: Is there a full text of the article with the proof? I couldn't find it anywhere, and my IEEE membership expired.

Comment: @T_M I cannot share it, it is copyrighted materials. There is no proof in the paper.

Comment: I understand. Then could you elaborate a bit more on how to proceed with the proof you gave when you defined $b$? @LaurentDuval

Comment: @T_M Seems simpler, I have modified the proof

Answer (score 2):

Your claim is wrong even if one of the norms is the Euclidean norm. Take $p=2, \ r=1, \ v=(0,0)$ and $x=(2,2)$. We take the following two norms

$$ \Vert (y,z) \Vert_1 := \sqrt{y^2+z^2}, \quad \Vert (y,z) \Vert_2:= \frac{1}{2} \max\{\vert y \vert, \vert z \vert \}.$$

Then 
$$ \min_{\Vert w \Vert_1=1} \Vert w - x \Vert_2 \geq  \frac{1}{2} > 0 = \vert \ \Vert x \Vert_2 - 1 \vert = \vert \ \Vert x - v \Vert_2 - r\vert.$$

Where we used

$$ \Vert x \Vert_2 =  \Vert (2,2) \Vert_2 = \frac{1}{2}\max\{ \vert 2 \vert, \vert 2 \vert \} = 1.$$

The first inequality follows from the following considersation.

$$1= \Vert (w_1, w_2) \Vert_1 \Rightarrow 1 = 1^2 = w_1^2 + w_2^2 \Rightarrow \max \{ \vert w_1\vert, \vert w_2 \vert \} \leq 1.$$
Thus, if $\Vert (w_1, w_2) \Vert_1 = 1 $, then

$$ \Vert (w_1, w_2) - x \Vert_2  = \frac{1}{2} \max \{ \vert w_1 - 2\vert, \vert w_2 - 2 \vert\} =\frac{1}{2} \max \{ 2- w_1, 2-w_2\} 
\geq \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: I literally have no idea how you calculated the norms. Could you clarify?

Comment: @T_M I hope this helps.